# How to create a button with 'Cancel' text which is language dependant?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, localization

I would like to add to the form an universal 'Cancel' button. By universal I mean that on a system with different than English locales it will display localized 'Cancel' string. How to achieve this?

Comment: Depends a bit on the frondend technology...

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the localization support provided by .NET and Visual Studio. See for example a walkthrough here: [Localizing Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).